# OAuth2 - Token expires when application is closed

Tags: java, android, oauth, oauth-2.0

I'm creating an android app that connects and retrieves data from Fitbit. As I'm new to OAuth2 I've used [RxSocialConnect-Android module](https://github.com/VictorAlbertos/RxSocialConnect-Android) (based on ScribeJava) to make the process easier. 
Everything works fine but when I close my app it says the token has expired. I did't expect this as this module stores tokens encrypted locally.

If anyone knows this module and can help me with this I would appreciate it.